# Convert Casia annotation to yolo format

Tags: python, annotations, yolo, darknet

I use darknet fork by AlexeyAB, I download the annotation and images of database Casia but i need to convert text files contains numbers in this format (x,y,z) exemple 110 182 104 
How to convert thoses files to yolo format annotation?

I'm trying to train my own dataset using CASIA iris detection , that i need to convert annotation to yolo format to use it with darknet.exe

I had annotation files in format (x,y,z) with theirs pictures

Comment: can you post input and expected output?

Comment: i think that should be like this (output file): 3 0.429 0.6973333333333334 0.854 0.16799999999999998  => format (<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>)

Comment: can you share your dataset sample with the corresponding sample image?